# How to insert array formula into Excel via VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Previously I have an Excel VBA code that performs index & match formula from 1 sheet to another for an entire column in a table. Code example as below:

```
With Me.Range("table1[Description]")
    .Formula = "=IFerror(INDEX(table2,MATCH(B4,table2[Asset No],0),2),"""")"
    .Value = .Value
 End With
```

Now I would like to add an array function into the sheet so I copied the formula and replace the old formula with array along with other modifications.

```
Sub refresh()

With Me.Range("table1[Last Service Date]")
    .FormulaArray = "=LARGE(IF(table2[[#All],[Asset No]]=[@[Asset No]],table2[[#All],[Entry Date]]),2)"
    .Value = .Value
End With

End Sub
```

But when I try to test the code, I keep getting the error message 400.
Anything I need to change in my code for array formulas?

Comment: Of course *on whatever cell I'm pointing on* because you use `Selection`.

Comment: oops.. Sorry, used my old test code by accident. I'll edit in the proper one.

Comment: It's good that you rephrased the [previous question][1] (now I understand your followup question) but some more info is needed on this one.  What is the rest of the error message, and on which line is it occurring?  Are you sure `Me.Range("table1[Last Service Date]")` is a valid range?  What happens if you try put a "regular" formula there like `.Formula="1+1"`?  Also, what is the purpose of `.Value = .Value`?

Comment: Glad to get that cleared up :p. Anyways `Me.Range("table1[Last Service Date]")` is valid for formulas at least. Cuz when I replaced array with 1+1 formula, the entire column auto creates 2 just as intended. As for the `.value = .value `, its a means to change the formula into values only. I don't need to keep the formula around in the table.

Comment: Also the error message just says `400`. That's it. The line causing it is on `.FormulaArray`.

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of using Me in the code? Have you placed that code in the Sheet Module? I would suggest you to move this code on to the Standard Module like Module1 and replace the Me keyword with the proper sheet reference. Otherwise I hope you have a good reason to place that code into the sheet module.

Also you should place the Array Formula in the first cell of the table in the desired column and since the data is formatted as an Excel Table, the whole column will be filled with the formula automatically. If not, you can then use AutoFill property to fill down the formula down the rows.

Give this a try to see if that resolves your issue.
The answer assumes that the formula you are trying to place through VBA works well when you put it manually on the Sheet.

```
With Me.Range("table1[Last Service Date]").Cells(1)
    .FormulaArray = "=LARGE(IF(table2[[#All],[Asset No]]=[@[Asset No]],table2[[#All],[Entry Date]]),2)"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: Actually, specifying the entire target range for the array formula is more efficient than specifying the first cell and then copy down.

Comment: I don't think that would work. Did you ever try implementing the Array Formula to the entire range through VBA?

Comment: Yes, I did. Excel 2010. `ArrRng.FormulaArray = "=MINVERSE(" & DataRange & ")"`